# FQL Query to retrieve photos works on newer Facebook accounts but not older ones

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

When I input the query below, I get an Ilist object with all photos in an album

```
"SELECT pid, src_small, src_big FROM photo WHERE aid = '100003240429199_12493' "
```

When I input this one below, I get 0 results.

```
"SELECT pid, src_small, src_big FROM photo WHERE aid = '730676042_444686' "
```

I am pulling the cover photo for an album. Here is the code:

```
var query = string.Format("SELECT pid, src_small, src_big FROM photo WHERE aid = '{0}' ", usrid + "_" + albid);
var result2 = (IList<object>)fb.Query(query);
string hold = "", pid = "", small = "", big = "";
foreach (object g in result2)
{
   hold = g.ToString();
   string[] sub = hold.Split(',');
   pid = sub[0].Replace("{\"pid\":\"", "");
   pid = pid.Replace("\"", "");

   small = sub[1].Replace("\"src_small\":\"", "");
   small = small.Replace("\"", "");

   big = sub[2].Replace("\"src_big\":\"", "");
   big = big.Replace("\"}", "");
   th = new FolderExplorer.ThumbNail(usrid + "_" + albid, big, small);
   thmbs.Add(th);
   break;
}
}
```

Why does the query not work with older facebook accounts (shorter userId's) - I tried several accounts and the results were consistent.

Answer (score 0):

My Facebook account is an older one and my album IDs have no underscore in them.  As far as I know, you can't generate an album ID based on their User ID.

You would be better off running a query like this to get all the cover photo for each user's album

```
fql?q=SELECT pid, src_small, src_big FROM photo WHERE object_id in (select cover_object_id from album where owner = me())
```

Comment: Your suggestion partially worked, the reponse contained the cover photo from the first album repeated for each successive album. However You showed me that I can use correlated subqueries in FQL, (which was discouraged in the documentation). I will play around with this to get what I need. Thanks much .. David